# IdP metadata format for spring-security-saml

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

While deploying the sample app from the Quick Start guide in spring-security-saml, I have an import error of the site metadata not clear to me:

```
- FrameworkServlet 'saml': initialization completed in 399 ms
Started Tomcat Server
The Server is running at http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample
- Next refresh cycle for metadata provider 'https://shibboleth.example.org/inner-metadata.xml' will occur on '2015-10-27T08:47:06.933Z' ('2015-10-27T09:47:06.933+01:00' local time)
- Metadata provider failed to properly initialize, fail-fast=true, halting
org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:267)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.doInitialization(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:236)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractMetadataProvider.initialize(AbstractMetadataProvider.java:407)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate.initialize(ExtendedMetadataDelegate.java:167)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.initializeProvider(MetadataManager.java:412)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.refreshMetadata(MetadataManager.java:238)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager.refreshMetadata(CachingMetadataManager.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager$RefreshTask.run(MetadataManager.java:1040)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.opensaml.saml2.common.SAML2Helper.getEarliestExpiration(SAML2Helper.java:112)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.processCachedMetadata(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:328)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:258)
    ... 9 more
- Initialization of metadata provider org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider@54b1cd failed, provider will be ignored
org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:267)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.doInitialization(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:236)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractMetadataProvider.initialize(AbstractMetadataProvider.java:407)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate.initialize(ExtendedMetadataDelegate.java:167)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.initializeProvider(MetadataManager.java:412)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.refreshMetadata(MetadataManager.java:238)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager.refreshMetadata(CachingMetadataManager.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager$RefreshTask.run(MetadataManager.java:1040)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.opensaml.saml2.common.SAML2Helper.getEarliestExpiration(SAML2Helper.java:112)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.processCachedMetadata(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:328)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:258)
    ... 9 more
```

The metadata at: `https://shibboleth.example.org/inner-metadata.xml` is a signed metadata used in the organization (a lot of SP data, some IdP) by Internet2 shibboleth-sp with no problems.

Which is the expected format of IdP metadata for spring-security-saml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the shipped example in the sample application, the IdP metadata contains data for a single IdP, in opposite to your organization metadata which very likely contains all SP and IdP metadata of all SAML actors in your site.

Try extracting the metadata for a single IdP.